# How to connect SAP Business One Service Layer using .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sapb1

I am unable to connect SAP Business One Service Layer using .NET Framework. It throws the error Internal Server Error with status code 500.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
                                            CompanyDB = "company",
                                            UserName = "username",
                                            Password = "password"
                                            }
                                      );
    var response = await client.PostAsync("service layer URL", new StringContent(json, 
    Encoding.Default, "application/json"));
```

Although I am able to connect to the service layer using the .NET Core application with the same code.

I have gone through this blog https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/15/how-to-consume-service-layer-odata-services-from-net-via-wcf/

But I am unable to Add Service Reference for the service layer.
I am not sure whether this problem belongs to the service layer or my program. Do we need to do extra code to call the OData service (as the service layer is oData V3 or V4) from the .net framework?
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Don't assume the problem is yours, the SL might be badly configured or not running properly at all. You can download SL logs from Landscape Directory (Services > Service Layer > Link). That might give you a steer on what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library called B1SLayer that aims to make Service Layer requests a lot easier with .NET, have a look:

https://github.com/bgmulinari/B1SLayer/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/B1SLayer/

Just create your SLConnection instance and the session is managed automatically. Check the GitHub page for request samples.

```
var serviceLayer = new SLConnection("https://sapserver:50000/b1s/v1", "CompanyDB", "manager", "12345");
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @jmoerdyk I'm not sure what you mean. He has a problem with the authentication and the authentication is handled automatically by the library, so there's nothing to demonstrate really as the library does that for him.

Comment: Hi @bgmulinari I came across you Nugget package but it appears you can't use it with building a blazor application project, can you share a light on that or give us an heads up on how to authenticate B1 Service Layer with session on Blazor or EF Core Api

Comment: Hi, @Matthew. Can you please [open an issue on B1SLayer's GitHub page](https://github.com/bgmulinari/B1SLayer/issues/new) to share more details on your problem? I'll gladly help, but I need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your login problem you could intercept the sent HTTP messages from both of your applications (.NET Framework vs. .NET Core) and compare them. For example by using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler).
You might find a little difference which prevents SL from processing your request.

I was able to connect to SL successfully in a .NET Core project by using the RestSharp library. Maybe this will get you started:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var client = new RestClient("https://<host>:<port>/b1s/v2");
  client.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
  {
    // allow all certificates for testing purposes
    return true;
  };
  var resolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
  // respect the names defined in the JsonProperty annotations
  resolver.NamingStrategy.OverrideSpecifiedNames = false;
  client.UseNewtonsoftJson(new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = resolver });

  var loginRequest = new RestRequest("Login");
  loginRequest.AddJsonBody(new LoginBody() { CompanyDB = "yourCompanyDb", UserName = "user1", Password = "myPassword" });
  var response = client.Post<LoginResponse>(loginRequest);

  if (response.Data != null)
  {
    var itemRequest = new RestRequest("Items('57387')"); // get an item
    // add the session cookie
    itemRequest.AddHeader("Cookie", $"B1SESSION={response.Data.SessionId}");
    var itemResponse = client.Get<Items>(itemRequest);
  }
}
```

The JSON POCOs:

```
  public class LoginBody
  {
    [JsonProperty("CompanyDB")]
    public string CompanyDB { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
  }
  
  public class LoginResponse
  {
    [JsonProperty("SessionId")]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
  }
  
  public class Items
  {
    [JsonProperty("ItemCode")]
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ItemName")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
  }
```

Regarding your question to add a Service Reference I am not sure what you want to achieve. If you want to generate a OData client along with all required classes and data models you might want to look at the [Unchase OData Connected Service](https://github.com/unchase/Unchase.Odata.Connectedservice) Visual Studio extension. For me this worked well since it generates a functioning SL/OData client based on the [Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.odata.client.dataservicecontext?view=odata-client-7.0) class. Please see the [OData client documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/getting-started) for more examples on how too use it.